# Looking for a Q&A/Feedback Website in C#

Tags: c#, user-feedback

I'm wondering if someone is aware of an open source C# initiative for a Q&A/Feedback Website similar to stackoverflow, getsatisfaction or even UserVoice. I try using a few keywords over Google and codeplex but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked for any open source MessageBoards

http://yetanotherforum.net/

Here. I found this question on another stackoverflow site.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: Not a bad idea, but they are using a GPLV2 license this seam to me to be a problem if I’m doing a commercial project.

Comment: I found this question on another site. I will add it to my post.